# Angular routerLink in Navbar is not working

Tags: angular, routerlink

I am following a tutorial and building my first Angular app (yay!).  I have followed all the steps but cannot seem to find my issue.  I am adjusting all of the *href* links in the navbar to be *routerLink* links.  I just tried to change the "Background" link and it isnt working.  I literally have tried even copy and pasting straight from the the Angular CLI website, but it still isn't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my *app-routing.module.ts* file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { AccomplishmentsComponent } from './accomplishments/accomplishments.component';
import { AdditionalInformationComponent } from './additional-information/additional-information.component';
import { BackgroundComponent } from './background/background.component';
import { IntroComponent } from './intro/intro.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from './skills/skills.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IntroComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'accomplishments', component: AccomplishmentsComponent },
  { path: 'additional-information', component: AdditionalInformationComponent },
  { path: 'background', component: BackgroundComponent },
  { path: 'intro', component: IntroComponent },
  { path: 'skills', component: SkillsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And here is my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Garbage Coder | Software Engineer</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Garbage Coder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>

                                                              <!--Issue is here-->
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" [title]="Background" [routerLink]="['/background']">Background</a>


            <a class="nav-item nav-link" [title]="Skills" href="#">Skills</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Accomplishments</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have u tried like this `routerLink="/backgrond"` without square bracket and check ur path is correct

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @KiranMistry I did check my path is correct.  When I manually type in /background in my local host, it does go to the correct routerLink.  I will try your edit now.

Comment: @gunjit the navbar doesn't appear as a link.  I can't click on it and it doesnt take me anywhere

Comment: @KiranMistry Your edit didn't work. :(

Comment: checkout this it will help u [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage%2Fdashboard.component.html)

Comment: @GarbageCoder you are referring to URL  http://localhost:4200/background or http://localhost:4200/{{ something }}/background

Comment: @RaviTeja when I type "localhost:4200/background" into my url bar, it goes to the page I want.

Comment: @GarbageCoder try this and tell me [routerLink]="['background']"

Comment: `[routerLink]='["/background"]'` should be the correct way to do it. If you are still not able to navigate, please create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue or update the question if you are getting any error messages in console.

Comment: all:
I have make a fork of @KiranMistry 's link.  You can find it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing-mpakgc

You will notice all of the href links work, however, the routerLink doesnt even have a hover state or do anything when clicked on.

Comment: @RamChandraNeupane I'm sorry, i don't understand.  I think what you want me to do is move my routerLink to the `app.component.html` file.  Is that correct?  How would this work with my nave bar then?

Comment: @GarbageCoder Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-r2cbzx

Comment: hii @GarbageCode Here Is My Stackblitz Code You Can Check What Wrong in ur code [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-596fwl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.)

Answer (score 2):

I've gone through your stackblitz demo. And found out that even if I type the url's to the components directly to the bar, it doesn't navigate.

I then checked the app module for the route configuration, and found out that you have mistake there.

```
const appRoute: Route = [
  { path: 'about', component: About },
  { path: 'service', component: Service },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard, canActivate: [] }
]
```

This should be changed like Route become Routes

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: About },
  { path: 'service', component: Service },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard, canActivate: [] }
]
```

import from here,

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

try it and let me know.

-----Edits------

Additional to this, you have multiple router outlets (one in app component html and other in the index.html), which isn't allowed in angular unless at least one of them is a named router outlet. Seems like these are the issues. And I strongly suggest you to keep the index.html file as it is when the initial project was generated by angular-cli. Write your code from app-component onwards to the child components.

Another one issue is you are not rendering the app component to the dom as you have changed the selector of app component from **app-root** to **my-app** but still using the tag **app-root** to render app component in index.html. Update that one as well, so that the app-component is rendered.

Comment: see this [stackblitz] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing-vun8by?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a working code

Answer (score 2):

After rewatching my tutorial, I discovered that the issue was my navbar needed to be inside the *app.component.html* instead of my *index.html* as @RamChandraNeupane suggested in the comments.  Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try it like this `routerLink="background"` remove the "/" and both square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to remove the brackets...

```
<div class="pl-20">
  <a class="color-grey2 font-14" routerLink="/transformer-management" routerLinkActive="active">
    <span>Transformers</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="pl-20">
   <a class="color-grey2 font-14" routerLink="/cost-file-management" routerLinkActive="active">
     <span>Costs</span>
   </a>
</div>
```